# Como calcular o total em um filtro no vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filtro, map

Esta aplicação `Vue` calcula os totais em uma lista como abaixo dentro de methods:

```
somaTotal(){
    let amounts = this.transactions.map(transaction => transaction.valor);
    return this.total = amounts
           .reduce((acc, item) => (acc += parseFloat(item)), 0)
           .toFixed(2);
}
```

o código HTML que mostra o total é o seguinte:

```
<td align="right"> 
    <b> 
        {{parseFloat(somaTotal())
           .toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
        }} 
    </b>
</td>
```

Tem este filtro que mostra a lista de acordo com o texto que digitamos:

```
computed: {
           filteredTransactions (){
              if(this.searchQuery){
                  return this.transactions.filter((transaction)=>{
                  return transaction.tipo.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
                 })
              }else{
                  return this.transactions;
              }
            }
      },
```

Como calcular o total dentro do filtro? Totalizando com base nos valores filtrados?

Answer (score 1):

Basta acrescentar

```
.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += parseFloat(item)), 0)
.toFixed(2);
```

no final desse computed.
Podes adaptar o método `somaTotal` para receber uma array e fazer isso assim:

```js
methods: {
    somaTotal(transactions) {
      let amounts = (transactions || this.transactions).map(transaction => transaction.valor);
      return this.total = amounts
        .reduce((acc, item) => (acc += parseFloat(item)), 0)
        .toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredTransactions() {
      let transactions = this.transactions;
      if (this.searchQuery) {
        transactions = this.transactions.filter((transaction) => {
          return transaction.tipo.startsWith(this.searchQuery);
        })
      }
      return somaTotal(transactions);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Ótimo. vou testar.

Comment: Você definiu somaTotal e methods e chamou somaValor.

Comment: Além disso, eu quero o total calculado dentro do filtro. Como você fez, calcula o total fora.

Comment: @FlavioCardoso erro meu, eu queria dizer o mesmo nome que o método que já tinhas. Corrigi.

Comment: @FlavioCardoso como assim "calculado fora"? Os `methods` podem e devem ser usados como ferramentas para outros métodos, computed, etc